# How to implement GWT, Java, button, and the clickhandler

Tags: java, gwt, button

Forgive me if this question has been asked and answered, as I have been unable to find it if it has.

I can find several examples like

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        ... stuff ...
    }
});
```

I'm trying to understand how to implement a button click handler using the following structure.

```
public class myClass implements EntryPoint {
    final Button MyButton = new Button("text");
        :
        :
    void onClickMyButton(???) {
            ... stuff ...
    }
        :
        :
}
```

To "me", this structure is more easily read and is just my preference in coding style. But I don't know how to implement it.

I'm using Eclipse and GWT for a Java Web App.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
public class myClass implements EntryPoint, ClickHandler {
    final Button myButton = new Button("text");
        :
        :
    myButton.addClickHandler(this);


    @Override
    void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            ... stuff ...
    }
}
```

or

```
public class myClass implements EntryPoint {
    final Button myButton = new Button("text");
        :
        :
    myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            onClickMyButton(event);
        }
    });

    private void onClickMyButton(ClickEvent event) {
            ... stuff ...
    }
}
```

The second one is much cleaner, and allows handling several buttons with separate methods.

Comment: I Like both, but I have a question about the first one. If I have multiple buttons (say 3), how to I identify which is hit? or is that where the second answer comes in to play?

Comment: Yes, the second one is much cleaner to do that. In the first one, you would need to call `event.getSource()` to know which button has been clicked (I guess, because don't have experience with GWT)

Comment: Also note that if you used UiBinder to build your view, you could simply annotate the method with `@UiHandler("myButton")`, assuming `MyButton` has been annotated with `@UiField`.